# Weather API, how to combine search parameters for more detailed location (city, state, country etc) to prevent location mix-ups

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, weather-api

I often use the openweathermap.org's api for playing around with new platforms and I've run into the same problem of being unable to define a specific enough query to find certain cities.

The api works easily for large cities like London, San Francisco, etc, but I have problems with smaller cities or cities with common names. For example, there is a city in California called Lafayette, but there is a larger city in Louisiana also called Lafayette.

A GET request to this url will return the weather for Louisiana 
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=Lafayette&units=imperial&APPID= + api_key

and a GET request to this url (using ',ca') will return some completely different location's weather (with a city id of 0)
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=Lafayette,ca&units=imperial&APPID= + api_key

I am very new at this so please let me know if there is a simple way to specify specific location queries to prevent returning data for incorrect locations.

Answer (score 2):

If using a city doesn’t work directly there are two other options. One is using its latitude and longitude and the other is using it’s id.

**Latitude/Longitude method:**

Use google maps to find the city you are wanting. Right click in the center somewhere and select `What's here`. You will be given latitude and longitude coordinates to use like this:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=37.9&lon=-122.1&units=imperial&APPID=62908047dc0cdba22f4915a3a79658fa
```

**City ID method:**

I show this option second because you want to get approx lat/lon to make sure you find the correct id. Look at http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt and search for the city (using Ctrl-F). Step through until you find the one that has similar Lat/Lon coordinates like:

```
5364226 Lafayette   37.885761   -122.118019 US
```

So now the URL to use is

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5364226& APPID=62908047dc0cdba22f4915a3a79658fa
```

**Note:** With the ID method, I did find that you get an error if you use find? In the url. If you use weather? Then it returns valid data for that city.